# WordPress disable all archive features

Tags: wordpress

Is there available to disable all WordPress' default archive mechanism?

For example:

```html
../2022
../category/xx
../?s=xx
../author/xx
../tax/term
etc.
```

If possible, I would like to activate and deactivate them separately in a programmable way. It would be nice to decide which one should work.